# Firebase -- exceeded quota number of reads

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, subscribe

I have created a simple firebase webapp, which is subscribed to listen for changes within a collection in firestore. As there are only 3 items in that collection, I was wondering how it was possible to reach the quota limit of 50k reads a day. I did leave the app running on localhost while I was away from my computer, which I am assuming is the reason that it reached the daily quota limit. But how was it possible to do that?

Basically, I have one page on my webapp that is subscribed to my collection in firestore. I then use that data retrieved to display it on the page.

[image]

As I said, there are only 3 items in the collection I am subscribed to. How does the subscription work? Is it constantly reading the database to watch for changes, or does it only do a read request when the collection changes (a doc being added or removed, for example)?

PS I have not even published this app to the web, so I don't think it's even possible for read requests to be coming from another computer.

Comment: How many times per day are those 3 items modified?

Comment: Yes my friend , It counts every call to a document. It is probably you made some intervals or something like interval and you reached out the limit. Firebase offers 2 kinds of read operation first is get data once and the second one is listen for any changes so be careful while reading data. It doesn't matter how many docs you have it matters how many times you make connection to those data. Might be nice to check this out https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Comment: The items were never really being modified, although I did occasionally add and delete an item to make sure it was working correctly. I will edit my question to be more specific with how I am reading data and displaying it. Thanks for the comments, guys

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You got a loop there
`useEffect` is triggered whenever `products` changes, and you are calling setProducts in the `useEffect` itself.

So i'm thinking that this has consumed all your daily quota.

Answer (score 0):

i think you using map in setProducts make it re-render thus sending get call to firebase many time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).